# ASP.NET MVC Template for New Object

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm exploring templates for the first time in ASP.NET MVC (5.1) and I've got a few custom `DisplayFor` and `EditorFor` templates and I'm curious how to go about a template for a new object entirely. Essentially I'm looking for an `EditorFor` template where I don't pass in a model.

Is there an easy way to go about this built in or do I have to mess around with extending the HtmlHelper? Granted, I could use a partial view to accomplish what I want, but I was hoping not to. I just want to say "Hey, `EditorFor`, make me a blank form for this type".

Comment: The naming convention is almost english, as in Display For <Someobject>.  I don't see how a `DisplayFor` or `EditorFor` would work if you don't pass an object (re: *looking for an `EditorFor template where I don't pass in a model*).

Comment: @ErikPhilips, you're correct. At one point I looked through the Html helpers for a `CreatorFor` helper that maybe acted as a blank canvas. Sadly, non exists. Looking through the source code, however, I notice that the internal template helper accepts a `DataBoundControlMode` enum. `DisplayFor` uses the `ReadOnly` value, while `EditorFor` uses the `Edit` value. The enum does have a third value, `Insert`: *Represents the insert mode, which enables users to enter values for a new record or data field.* Looks like I'll have to implement my own `CreatorFor` helper. Name pending...

Comment: What is `CreateFor` going to do different then `EditorFor`. The problem it appears is you are confusing the word `Edit` for the word `Editor`.  The Editor is good for editing existing content, and creating new content.

Comment: @ErikPhilips, I think you might be confused. You say *"..., and creating new content."* Great, that's what I want. If possible, I want to use the `EditorFor` to create new content, meaning, I want it to output empty form fields, which means I shouldn't be passing in a model. If anything, I should just let it know what object I want it create the blank fields for. So, how do I accomplish said task with `EditorFor`, which is what my original question was about?

Comment: Maybe we're just not understanding each other. Let me put it this way. I have an object called `Address`. For that object I have a `DisplayFor` template *DisplayTemplates/Address.cshtml*, an `EditorFor` template *EditorTemplates/Address.cshtml*, and a `Partial` view *Partials/Address.cshtml*. There is no difference between the `EditorFor` and the `Partial` other than me passing in `null` for the values in the `Partial`. Ideally, I'd like not to use the `Partial` and just use the `EditorFor` to create new objects as well without having to pass in a model, which I wouldn't have anyway.

Comment: why wouldn't you pass an new (empty) object?  Not passing in an object to a method that is an editor for an object...

Comment: @ErikPhilips, we're not getting anywhere. Perhaps you missed the very first sentence in my question where I said I'm exploring templates **for the first time**. Since you seem to know something that *I obviously* don't, why don't you add an answer with an example of how I *should* be using `EditorFor` to create new objects?

Answer (score 0):

May be `DisplayForModel()`, `EditorForModel()` and `LabelForModel()` helpers could help you.